# How to create search form using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form name="myForm" id="search" action="search.php?searching=true" method="post" >
    <table cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px"><br/><br/>   
        <tr>
            <td><?php if(!empty($row1)){ ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (!empty($row1['id']))?$row1['id']:""?>">
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="save" value='1'>
                <?php } ?>  
                <th style="float:left">First Name:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</th>
            </td>
            <td>
                &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                <select name="salute" class="select" value="<?php echo (!empty($row1['salute']))?$row1['salute']:""?>">
                    <option>Mr.</option>
                    <option>Ms.</option>
                    <option>Mrs.</option>
                    <option>Dr.</option>
                    <option>Prof.</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="text"  placeholder="Name is..." onblur="return validName();" onfocus="document.getElementById('fname_error').innerHTML=''"/><br/>
                <label id="fname_error"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <th style="float:left">
                    <span><sup>*</sup></span>Last Name:&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                </th>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lname" class="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo (!empty($row1['lname']))?$row1['lname']:""?>" onblur="return validLname();" onfocus="document.getElementById('lastname_error').innerHTML=''"/> <br/>
                <label id="lastname_error"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table align="center" cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px"><br/><br/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" name="search" id="search" />&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table align="center" border="2" bgcolor="white" cellspacing="1px" cellpadding="20px"><br/><br/>
        <tr bgcolor="#4d7fea">
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Pin</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Pin</th><th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['fname'])){
                $params['name']=$_REQUEST['salute']." ".$_REQUEST['fname']." ".$_REQUEST['lname'];
                $sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE Name LIKE '%".trim($params['name'])."%'";
                $records=$db->mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['state']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['pin']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['city1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['state1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['country1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['pin1']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><span style='color:Purple'><b>Edit</b></span>&emsp;
            <a href="index.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure?')"><span style="color:Red"><b>Delete</b></span>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php }  }else{ ?>
        <tr><b>No Data Found</b></tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: what's the issue? what re you actually doing? also where is search form code?

Comment: this query is not working

Comment: i create  a form with all above details and insert data in database. now i want to search by name. i want if i enter name then the row will come.

Comment: try to run that query directly in phpmyadmin with hardcoded value and check what is coming?

Comment: Also form code is needed too

Comment: query woks in phpmyadmin but in .php page it doesn't give output.

Comment: You use Name in query.. Try to use name in query..... $sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE '%".trim($params['name'])."%'";

Comment: There is only connection problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Search you have to add % tag in your query:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE Name LIKE '%".trim($params['name'])."%'";
```

This worked.

Answer (score 2):

search string anywhere in text useing '%':

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE Name LIKE '%".trim($params['name'])."%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   if (!empty($_REQUEST['fname'])){
                    $params['name']=$_REQUEST['salute']." ".$_REQUEST['fname']." ".$_REQUEST['lname'];
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM test WHERE Name LIKE '%".trim($params['name'])."%'";  

                    $records=mysqli_query($db->conn,$sql);
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){ ?>
```